# Uninstall Xcode 4 when it was installed via the App Store

Tags: xcode, xcode4, uninstallation

I understand that those who installed Xcode 4 via the developer site are able to uninstall via `/Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools –mode=all`, however I installed via the App store and there doesn't seem to be an executable with the word "uninstall" in the name anywhere in the Developer folder at all. Any suggestions on how I should go about uninstalling Xcode 4?

Comment: To clarify, I installed Xcode 4 on a fresh install of OS 10.6, so there were no previous versions of Xcode present on the system.

Comment: I can confirm the new location given works. Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This help for Xcode before MAS install
/Library/Developer/Shared/uninstall-devtools

If you install it from MAS you can remove from launchpad, 
but also need to remove some folders** and files created by this app, you can use some helper application that found this files and safely remove it :)

** ex.: ~/Library/Developer, ~/Library/Application Support/Xcode, ~/Library/iPhone Simulator, Logs and etc.

Comment: Unfortunately I gave up and reformatted/reinstalled my system (I know, definitely overkill) so I could get a clean install of 3.2.6, so I can't confirm this. However, I only searched the /Developer folder, so I guess it makes sense I would have missed it if it were in the /Library/Developer folder.

Comment: I tired that, it removed some stuff, but nto all of it

Comment: LOL not any more for Xcode 4.3 :D Are they changing all folder locations with every update now?

Comment: Don't do it this way. Do it via the launch pad http://stackoverflow.com/a/13237725/79835

Comment: Not only this :) You also need remove all subfolders for this app in ~/Library/Developer, ~/Library/Application Support/Xcode, ~/Library/iPhone Simulator, Logs and etc. :) Or you can use some app for find all files created by this app and remove

Answer (score 11):

From the above comment, the correct way is to:

1. Run sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools –mode=all
2. Delete "/Applications/Install Xcode" if you want the app store to allow you to reinstall it.

Comment: Suresh's answer seems to be the correct way to do it if you installed it from the app store http://stackoverflow.com/a/13237725/79835

Answer (score 5):

If you have installed xcode from Mac App store, then you need to delete it from Launch pad. You can do this by locating xcode icon in launch pad, long click on the icon till it starts dancing. Then delete it and wait for a while till the xcode.app is deleted from /Application. If you manually delete xcode.app from /Application, App store will continue to think its installed and will not allow you to reinstall in future.

Comment: This worked for me on OS X 10.8.2 with XCode 4.5.2. Thanks very much suresh, took a lot of searching to finally find this right answer :)

Answer (score 0):

In our installs of xCode 4 from the App Store, we are able to use:

```
sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-developer-folder
```

Comment: Worked for me- but how do I reinstall since the appstore still thinks it's there?

Comment: Try here method (expand bash string in site): [link](http://itux.idev.pro/2011/08/idevmicro-xcode-полная-чистка-компьютера/)

Comment: I had to delete "/Applications/Install Xcode" for App Store to allow me to reinstall Xcode. Credit: http://tuts.pinehead.tv/2011/08/29/how-to-uninstall-xcode-from-mac-app-store/

Answer (score 0):

You must uninstall first the

**sudo /Library/Developer/Share/uninstall-devtools –mode=all**

It might be something else in your particular case so maybe you can try

**locate uninstall-devtools** to find where the script is placed.

Then you can find the version you need of xcode from https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action

IMPORTANT: If you are going to install a previous version of the Developer Tools, be sure to restart the machine after installing.