# How do I set the background image of a UISegmentedControl

Tags: iphone, ios, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a view with a segmentedcontrol in it and I would like to set the background image of that control. I know that I can change set the tint color, but I want more control over it than that. So if I could set a background image that would be cool.

I found [this tutorial on how to achieve this](http://www.secxtanx.com/segbuttons.html), however it's outdated, and I'm unable to get it working.

Could anyone please help me? I greatly appreciate any help.

## UPDATE

Half the solution has been found, if the only thing one needs to support is iOS5 you can use setBackgroundImage:forState:barMetrics:. [A great tutorial on the matter can be found here.](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4344/user-interface-customization-in-ios-5)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this?: [setBackgroundImage:forState:barMetrics:](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/Reference/UISegmentedControl.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006807-CH3-SW38)

Straight from the docs

**Note**: Available in iOS 5.0 and later.

Comment: I have had some trouble updating Xcode to 4.2, so I don't have the ios5 sdk yet. However I will try this out when ever the download of xcode 4.2 is done. Thanks though!

If anyone have trouble upgrading to 4.2 heres a post that explains how to fix it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5344226/uninstall-xcode-4-when-it-was-installed-via-the-app-store

Comment: :) Yeah the only gotcha is the users who havent upgraded to iOS5. I guess you'll have to be a little smarter about handling those cases by subclassing the UISegmentedControl (there are tonnes of tutorials on customizing it). Subclassing it, though slightly painful, is not impossible.... I've written a subclass for it myself which colors the text labels for the segments differently based on what's selected..

Comment: Unfortunately iOS5 shouldn't be supported exclusively (in most cases), and with something as visual as this, I can't see why you would use this for now at least. If you go to all the effort to create custom views to simulate a segmented view, why would you also support the real thing ?

Comment: Well as of now it's at the clumsy stage where users are moving over to iOS5. It isn't too much extra work to check if the device responds to setBackgroundImage:forState:barMetrics.... so I just threw it in there :) I guess it's kind of OCD-ish but I'd rather have the device run standard API code if it can be helped :)